# Using OR r/m32, imm32 in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, amd-processor

The opcode generated by:

```
or ebx, 0ffffffffh
```

with NASM is:

```
83CBFF
```

But in Intel Instructions Manual:

```
81 /1 id      OR r/m32, imm32
83 /1 ib      OR r/m32, imm8
```

My question is, why NASM used the opcode `83` instead of `81`, and how to generate the opcode `81`?

this is the command line for NASM: `nasm    -fwin32    file.asm    -l list.lst`

Comment: why use imm32 when you can use imm8 and save a few bytes?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc e.g. to align a loop.

Comment: You can write `or eax, strict dword 0ffffffffh` to force a 32-bit operand. But this causes NASM to use the 0D opcode (`or eax, imm32`) instead of 81. Of course, you can always just output the needed bytes with `db`.

Comment: @interjay thank's, I've changed `eax` to `ebx` to avoid the special case of `OR EAX, imm32`

Comment: how about [`ALIGN` macro](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.11.12)?

Comment: I think `ALIGN` just causes NASM to emit a series of `NOP`s, @Ped7g, which is less efficient than a longer form of the same instruction. Might work in other assemblers, though. MASM is a bit smarter in how it adds padding.

Comment: @CodyGray: In NASM, you can `%use smartalign` then `ALIGNMODE p6, 32`.  YASM has a much nicer default, using long NOPs in a way that's optimal for Intel P6 and SnB uarches.  (Probably controlled by a `CPU` directive or something, I forget).  GNU `as`'s `.p2align` also uses long NOPs by default.  NASM is the exception, with nasty behaviour that will break the uop-cache by default.  (More than 18 uops in a 32-byte chunk means that the code has to run from the decoders every time).

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was remembering about NASM's default behavior being quite undesirable. YASM, Gas, and MASM all do the right thing without any extra work required. I'd forgotten about `smartalign`, though, probably because I've never actually used it and it didn't get cemented in long-term memory.

Comment: @Ped7g: No current assemblers know how to stretch instructions before an `ALIGN` directive, unfortunately.  So you always get NOPs, instead of making the same instructions take more space "for free".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NASM picks the 8-bit sign-extended immediate encoding as an optimization, because it does the same thing (`-1` is representable in 8-bit 2's complement) and takes less space. You can force NASM to use a specific encoding with:

```
or ebx, strict dword 0ffffffffh
```

This results in:

```
81 cb ff ff ff ff
```

Assembling the original code without optimizations (`nasm -O0`) will also give this result.

Note that if the register is EAX, doing this will result in the 0D opcode (`or eax, imm32`) instead of 81. So in that case you might have to output the instruction yourself: `db 0x81, 0xc8, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff`.

Comment: I wonder how it does the same thing, does it apply the byte operand to the all bytes of the dword?

Comment: The `imm8` is sign extended.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu ["In the forms with an 8-bit immediate second operand and a longer first operand, the second operand is considered to be signed, and is sign-extended to the length of the first operand. In these cases, the BYTE qualifier is necessary to force NASM to generate this form of the instruction."](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html)

Comment: awesome. so it wouldn't be the same effect for 01h.